# use the mydate class defined in java. Create an object for date hired. How do I do this?

Tags: java

how to use mydate class defined ?

```
package lab4;

public class MyDate {
    private int month, day, year;

    public MyDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: thnx for answers but what I mean is use the mydate class define in programming.Create an object for date hired for an employee.

Comment: An employee has
an office, salary, and date hired. Use the MyDate class defined in Programming
Exercise 10.14 to create an object for date hired. A faculty member has office
hours and a rank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this:

```
MyDate dateHired = new MyDate(monthHired, dayHired, yearHired);
```

monthHired, dayHired, and yearHired are all integer representations. [0-12] month [0-31] day and [0-Integer.Max] year :)

The MyDate class still needs getters and possibly some setters for the variables.. So just read in 3 numbers from somewhere and create a MyDate object just like that!